# Seaborn scatter, set size consistent between plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

So I've got two scatterplots of similar data but a different occurrence rate. I have plotted them with sizes=(0.01,200). But as the frequency varies between plots the sizes are not consistent. I've spent a lot of time googling but not sure how to easily set a consistent scale that also fits my min/max of (0.01,200). Below is the varying scales between plots. Is there a simple way to ensure that lets say 6000 = 200 between plots and for all sizes in my range?

Thanks!

[![plot 1 [1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example, perhaps with a sample data set?

Comment: In theory, `hue_norm` should be the answer here, but I think this question has exposed a bug in using `hue_norm` to extrapolate beyond the range of data values.

Comment: See https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2539